# How to access delegate returned parameters outside of the delegate method?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uipickerview

I've got a `UIViewController` with a UIPicker on it and I've got the `- (void)sourcePickerViewController:(SourcePickerViewController *)controller etc...` which returns several bits of data (the etc...) to it's delegate.  Inside the delegate method, I see the values I want and can output them via `NSLog` but I can't figure out how to use them elsewhere in the code.  In the same `UIViewController` that has that delegate method in it, I have another method that should update some `UITextFields` based on the data returned, but I get errors like `dataVariableName undeclared`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the delegate method is called store references to the variables in your delegate class, then you will be able to use them in other methods.